# how to get element class with condition children value determine?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Updated** 
i has code ex:

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu-0">
     <input class="id" type="text" value="1"/>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-0">
     <input class="id" type="text" value="2"/>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-0">
     <input class="parent_id" type="text" value="2"/>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-0">
     <input class="parent_id" type="text" value="2"/>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-0">
     <input class="id" type="text" value="3"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

so i want addClass `parent-0` to li with condition this li  children input class `id` val() = this li next() children input class `parent_id` val().

it like

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu-0">
     <input class="id" type="text" value="1"/>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-0 parent-0">
     <input class="id" type="text" value="2"/>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-0 children-parent-0">
     <input class="parent_id" type="text" value="2"/>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-0 children-parent-0">
     <input class="parent_id" type="text" value="2"/>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-0 ">
     <input class="id" type="text" value="3"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

how to made it. thanks :]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('.menu-0').each(function(){
     if($(this).children('input').val() == '2')
    {
       $(this).addClass('parent-0');
    }
});
```

Or more generic:

```
$('li').each(function(){
     var num = $(this).attr('class').split('-').reverse();
     if($(this).children('input').val() == '2')
    {
       $(this).addClass('parent-'+num[0]);
    }
});
```